# Adjusting div height does not work with empty cache

Tags: jquery

I have two divs, one needs to be same size as another.

```
var someheight = $('.firstdiv').height();
$('.seconddiv').height(someheight);
```

This code works alright, unless i load page with empty cache - in this case it does not run at all. I need to reload page to get it started.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'empty cache'?

Comment: Browser cache. That one that can be reloaded by pressing Ctrl F5.

Comment: Do those `div` elements contain `img` elements? If so you need to wait for them to load before you get the height of the div.

Comment: Actually no, just text. Second div is nearly empty bat has to match first one filled with text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to respond to the window `resize` and `load` events, presumably you have resources like images in `.firstdiv` that change its height when they load. So if you run your code too early, it uses the wrong height, and then the image loads and changes the `.firstdiv` height.

E.g.:

```
function syncHeights() {
    var someheight = $('.firstdiv').height();
    $('.seconddiv').height(someheight);
}
syncHeights();
$(document).ready(syncHeights);
$(window).on("load resize", syncHeights);
```

The first call is the most proactive, then we call again when the DOM is complete, then we call *again* on `load` or `resize`. (If your script is at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and you're using an up-to-date version of jQuery, you can leave off the `ready` call, it's redundant [though harmless]. There was a bug a few versions back, though, which made `height` not entirely reliable prior to DOM ready. It got fixed.)

Note that you need the `resize` regardless of whether images are loading; since the size of `.firstdiv` is apparently not static (otherwise you'd just be using a static height for `.seconddiv`), presumably changes to the size of the window could change its height.